# What animal makes this sound vs What kind of animal makes this sound?

Tags: sentence-patterns

I am Chinese, a children's English teacher. What is the difference between these questions I might ask my students?

> "Meow." What animal makes this sound?
>
> "Meow." What kind of animal makes this sound?"

Comment: Why do you think there’s a difference? Most people would not, although I suppose dubious rescue readings are always possible.

Answer (score 2):

In certain instances, a question formulated as "What kind of X...?" may be preferable to the same question formulated as "What X...?" For example, in  U.S. English, people often ask "What kind of dog do you have?" whereas the alternative question "What dog do you have?" is less common and may strike some hearers as being slightly ill-formed or incomplete. A more clear-cut example would be the idiomatic rhetorical question "What kind of fool do you think I am?"—where the short, non-idiomatic form "What fool do you think I am?" seems by contrast to be requesting nominations for a most-similar fool. And hearers are very likely to understand the questions "What kind of bar is this?" and "What bar is this?" as seeking fundamentally different information. The first seems to be asking for a category of bar—fern bar, singles bar, sports bar, gay bar, etc., while the second seems to be asking what the name of the bar is—Rudy's Tavern, Shots on Fifth, The Inhaler, etc.

But that's not the case with "What kind of animal makes this sound?" and "What animal makes this sound?" Here a native U.S. English speaker will automatically, effortlessly, and immediately supply the understood "kind of" to "What animal makes this sound?" without even being aware of it. The same goes for such allied phrases such as "What car do you drive?" "What music do you like?" and "What ice cream is your favorite?" The number of question pairs where the version that includes "kind of" and the version that omits it it are completely interchangeable is by no means small.

I don't know of any reliable way to predict when  including "kind of" in the question will make no difference (as with "What kind of animal makes this sound?"), a minor difference in completeness (as with "What kind of dog do you have?"), a significant difference in idiomatic accuracy (as with "What kind of fool do you think I am?"), or a fundamental difference in perceived meaning (as with "What kind of bar is this?"). Maybe it's the sort of thing you learn by osmosis through continued exposure to the language, or maybe you discover instances where the wording makes a difference by asking a question in one form and receiving answers that weren't what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> *'What (kind of) animal makes this sound? Meow!'*

OR

> *'What animals make this sound? Meow!'*

To which they should reply, 'A cat!' or 'Cats!'

However, because you are an English teacher, I think you may benefit from my correcting the English of your question.

> *I am Chinese and I teach (Chinese) children (the) English (language).*

If you were you say 'I am a Chinese', the phrase is not complete.  The word 'Chinese' here is serving as an adjective, not a noun, so you have to be a Chinese *something*, in this case, a Chinese teacher.  So your sentence could have looked like this:

> *I am a Chinese teacher of English.*

Then the question itself...

> *When I want my students to answer my question, which sentence I should use "Meow","What animal make this sound " or "What kind of animal make this sound?"*

This needs to be reworded for clarity, I think.

> *Which sentence should I ask my students? 'What animal makes this sound? Meow!' or 'What kind of animal makes this sound? Meow!'*

I hope that helped!  I love cats.

Comment: *I am Chinese* and *I am a Chinese* are both correct. In the second sentence, *Chinese* is being used as a nominal. I am from America, I am an *American*.